# Room DB - DISTINCT for combination of 2 fields (GPS)

Tags: java, android, android-room

How to get unique GPS locations from RoomDB?

My entity has GPS latitude and longitude

```
@Entity
public class Location {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
public int id;

@ColumnInfo(name = "GPS_lat")
double GPSlat;

@ColumnInfo(name = "GPS_lon")
double GPSlon;
```

my dao with query

```
 // Read all
@Query("SELECT * FROM location")
List<Location> getLocations();enter code here

// Read only unique combination of GPS location 
 ?
```

I was playing with DISTINCT or group by, but still - no idea how to apply those to 2 dB columns at the same time, thanks

Answer (score 1):

**DISTINCT** is applied to an entire extracted row so you would be limited to just extracting the 2 columns (which would perhaps be of little use).

**GROUP BY** would be what you want and you simply use

- `@Query("SELECT * FROM location GROUP BY GPS_lat,GPS_lon")`
- Note that the content of other columns should be considered as **ambiguous** for columns that do not have the same value for all the rows that have effectively been condensed into one row. However, [aggregate functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) such as `sum`, `count` do consider the column values.

  - Note that **DISTINCT** can also be used within aggregate functions

Consider this example in native SQL :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS locations;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS locations (name TEXT, GPS_long INTEGER, GPS_lat INTEGER);
INSERT INTO locations VALUES ('place1',1,1),('place2',2,1),('place3',1,1),('place4',2,1),('place5',3,3),('place6',3,3),('place7',1,1),('place8',2,1);
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM locations;
SELECT DISTINCT GPS_long,GPS_lat FROM locations;
SELECT 
    *, 
    group_concat(name) AS all_places, -- aggregate function
    count(*) AS same_location -- aggregate function
FROM locations 
GROUP BY GPS_long,GPS_lat;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS locations;
```

This

- DROPS the table (for testing).
- CREATES the table
- INSERTS rows (3 groups of locations 3 rows at location 1,1, 2 rows at location 2,1 and 2 at location 3,3)
- SELECTS all columns using DISTINCT (they are all different)
- SELECTS just the GPS_long and GPS_lat columns using DISTINCT (resulting in 3 rows)
- SELECTS all columns and some additional columns using aggregate functions using GROUP BY GPS_long,GPS_lat (results in 3 rows but aggregated data)
- DROPS the table (to clean-up after the testing)

The results being :-

**1st Query** (DISTINCT on all columns)

[image]

**2nd Query** (DISTINCT on GPS_long and GPS_lat columns i.e. only those columns extracted)

[image]

**3rd Query** (All columns + using GROUP BY GPS_long, GPS_lat)
[image]

- note how the `group_concat` function gets the name for all places at the same location.